# Robo 3T connect to mongodb using ssh

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I have setup mongodb to listen on 27017 on 127.0.0.1 only. I need to keep it this way to have security on my database. Though i need to be able to connect to mongodb remotely using the Robo 3T. Is there any way to connect using the ssh connection to tunnel the connection to the localhost listening mongodb using my ssh credentials?

P.S. I kinda beginner to the mongoDB. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can use the mongo shell using ssh  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SSH tunnel.

Go to: `MongoDB Connections (Ctrl + N)` > `Create` / `Edit` > `SSH` tab

Answer (score 3):

I've done few configurations on my Ubuntu 18 Vagrant box in order to successfully connect MongoDB remotely using Robo 3T GUI. I've explained in the following steps.

1. On Ubuntu server, to open mongo shell run:

   ```
   $ mongo
   ```
2. Inside mongo shell, type following command to create new a admin user.

   ```
   > use admin;
   > db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"password", roles:[{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});
   ```
3. By default mongodb is configured to allow connections only from localhost(IP 127.0.0.1). We need to allow remote connections from any ip address. The following change should only be done in your development server. Open up  **etc/mongod.conf** file and do the following change.

   ```
   # network interfaces
       net:
           port: 27017
           bindIp: 0.0.0.0   #default value is 127.0.0.1
   ```

   Also in the same **mongod.conf** file uncomment security option and add *authorization* option as shown below.

   ```
   security:
       authorization: enabled
   ```
4. Save and exit the **mongod.conf** file and  restart mongodb server.

   ```
   $ sudo service mongod restart
   ```
5. Download and install Robo 3T GUI tool.
6. On Robo 3T GUI, in the connection settings, you need to do few changes as shown on
   below screen shots.

[image]

Enter mongodb **admin** database username and password which you have created earlier.

[image]

Here, I have entered my Ubuntu 18 Vagrant box ssh credentials.

[image]

Save the changes and press *connect* icon to see if the connection is working fine.

Comment: You shouldn't allow mongo server to accept connections from 0.0.0.0 IP from the security perspective. You should bind it to one IP (or several, if possible) but never from all of them.

Comment: The configuration only for personal development.

Answer (score 1):

Just achieved that

1. No need to change nothing in your mongodb settings
2. In robomongo use localhost:27017 as you db address
3. In SSH tab add your login details.