# MongoURI for database hosted on lightsail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, robo3t

I have successfully hosted a MongoDB database on lightsail using these post:

[post1](https://medium.com/@calvin.hsieh/steps-to-install-mongodb-on-aws-ec2-instance-62db66981218),[post2](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-install-mongodb-on-aws-lightsail-part-1-317),[post3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523341)

Also, made a successful connection using robo3T.

However, can't figure out the mongoURI, to make a connection from a nodejs server.

According to this [post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html):

mongoURI is: `` 'mongodb://<sample-user>:<password>@sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/sample-database?', { tlsCAFile: `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` }, ``

But, can't figure out what`<sample-cluster>` and `<node>` is.

Service endpoint for Lightsail is : `lightsail.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`[amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lightsail.html)

db.hostInfo() on robo3T, gives hostname as: `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal`(if it is important)

So tried this: `mongodb://admin:password@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.lightsail.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:27017/sample-database?retryWrites=true&w=majority` , but got `MongooseServerSelectionError`

What might be the right mongoURI?
Appreciate the help.

Also, has anyone tried to run mongo on Lightsail? What was your experience with regards to cost and maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

That AWS documentation you linked to is for AWS DocumentDB, not MongoDB running on LightSail. That's a totally different setup, and I wouldn't refer to that documentation at all in your case.

You just need to be looking at the main [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

> The standard URI connection scheme has the form:
>
> ```
> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
> ```

So your connection URI would look like:

```
mongodb://your-user:your-password@your-lightsail-hostname:27017/your-database-name
```

Replacing the values off `your-user`, `your-password`, `your-lightsail-hostname` and `your-database-name`

Comment: Hey, Mark. Thanks for the suggestion. As per your answer, I tried the following URI: `MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:<password>@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:27017/sample-database?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, `MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:<password>@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/sample-database?retryWrites=true&w=majority` and `MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:<password>@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal.amazonaws.com:27017/sample-database?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. None of them worked. Continued to get `MongooseServerSelectionError`

Comment: Are you running that code from your local computer, or from the same computer that MongoDB is running on? Also there should be more info in the error than what you are posting. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2) as an example of the entire error message you need to include in your question.